# Saving data in the table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How I can save this:

`a=1`
`b=2`
`c=3`
`d=4`

into the table like this (I do not need header):

`1 2 3 4`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If create `DataFrame` there is default header:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a,b,c,d]])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this:

```
table = [a, b, c, d]
print(table)
```

prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```